# Data needs transformation

Tags: json, grafana, jsonata

We have a system that returns timeseries in a rather strange manner -- in a single object with separated `Values` and `TimeStamps`, e.g:

```
[
    {
        "Location": "a2a127e8-0000-0000-0000-5dd95f33203b/1",
        "Keyinfo": {
            "Name": "Temperature"
        },
        "Values": [
            20.4627780914307,
            20.4127216339111,
            20.3624877929688
        ],
        "TimeStamps": [
            "2023-06-21T00:57:54+06:00",
            "2023-06-21T04:38:02+06:00",
            "2023-06-21T04:52:33+06:00"
        ]
    }
]
```

Full example for tests https://pastebin.com/raw/TdtqdGM3

It is pretty simple to fix it with any programming language (e.g, using a proxy or other middleware), but I want to stay using direct connection via [JSON API datasource](https://grafana.github.io/grafana-json-datasource/).

Is it possible to bring it to the desired form with one or more transformations? with built in tools or with another plugins. Are there plugins with custom coding?

`grafana version 10.0.0`

Answer (score 0):

Given that we are talking about JSON, we can try to use such a powerful tool as Jsonata. So we can take a datasource plugin with Jsonata support, e.g [JSON API](https://grafana.com/grafana/plugins/marcusolsson-json-datasource/) plugin.

Then for the given example we can try to transform single object to many iterating over e.g timestamps:

```
(
    /* Remember mattering values in variables */
    $location := Location;
    $values := Values;
    $name := Keyinfo.Name;
    
    /* Loop over timestamps */
    TimeStamps ~> $map(function($v, $i){
        /* $v - is an iterating objects (timestamps) */
        /* $i - is incrementing index */
        {
            "Location": $location,
            "Name": $name,
            "TimeStamp": $v,
            "Value": $values[$i]

        }
    })
)
```

Full example for pastebined code: https://try.jsonata.org/os1cm_IWU

So we have a list of objects in our result and we have to extract wanted values from this frame, like this:

[image]

And the final result for the pastebined code:
[image]